# Is React-Native is a good option for for android development?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React library for making frontened part for atleat more than 1 year.
So, using React-Native for android development is a good option for me or not?

I am basically a MERN stack developer. So, I am trying to learn android development also.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a MERN stack developer then it's good to start your Mobile development with React native. You will not only make apps for android but for iOS as well. Even you are focusing more on Android apps development then React Native is good option. The reason is simple: you are working in React (javascript or Typescript) so basically it's almost same for mobile as well, and about native code that's not a rocket science. Good Luck :)